# Convert a string into associative array which having a separator in it. Left side should be the key and right side value

Tags: php

Is there a way to convert a string having a separator in it such that the left side of the separator should be the key and right side should be the value. I am expecting the following output. The separator here in the example is "#"

```
<?php
$string = "1#Om Shanker, 2#John, 3#Jack, 4#Jill";
/*
  Expected output array
*/
$array = array(
"1" =>  "Om Shanker",
"2" =>  "John",
"3" =>  "Jack",
"4" =>  "Jill"
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this

```
<?php
$string = "1#Om Shanker, 2#John, 3#Jack, 4#Jill";
$str=explode(",",$string);
$newarr=array();
foreach($str as $k=>$v)
{
$newStr=explode('#',$v);
$newarr[trim($newStr[0])]=$newStr[1];
}

var_dump($newarr);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
array(4) {
  [1]=>
  string(10) "Om Shanker"
  [2]=>
  string(4) "John"
  [3]=>
  string(4) "Jack"
  [4]=>
  string(4) "Jill"
}
```